# Mongoose not returning data for aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have route that uses the following function to sum up the total revenue from registrations. It works just fine in the shell and via Studio3T but mongoose API doesn't return anything.

I am running mongoose 5.0.17 and using Azure Cosmos DB.

---

```
exports.getDhashboard = function (req, res) {
  Registration.aggregate({
    $group: {
      _id: "$challenge.name",
      totalAmount: { $sum: "$amount" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}, function (err, registrations) {

    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(registrations);
  });
};
```

---

Here is some sample JSON that is coming from the registrations collection.

```
{
        "modified": "2018-06-09T15:43:02.288Z",
        "_id": "5b1bf5863ace0d3f54be45b4",
        "paymentState": "approved",
        "paymentTimeStamp": "2018-06-09T15:43:02.000Z",
        "paymentId": "PAY-1J368604337116737LMN7K3I",
        "payPalBuyerEmail": "kameron.berget-buyer@theitfc.com",
        "payPalBuyerId": "TTJC5ZWWEF9E6",
        "address1": "1 Main St",
        "city": "San Jose",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "95131",
        "paymentMethod": "paypal",
        "paymentStatus": "VERIFIED",
        "amount": 20,
        "user": "",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "modified": "2018-06-10T14:58:49.422Z",
        "_id": "5b1d3ca9d586d4697021c128",
        "paymentState": "approved",
        "paymentTimeStamp": "2018-06-10T14:58:46.000Z",
        "paymentId": "PAY-0D492814K5815962PLMOTZCQ",
        "payPalBuyerEmail": "",
        "payPalBuyerId": "TTJC5ZWWEF9E6",
        "address1": "1 Main St",
        "city": "San Jose",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "95131",
        "paymentMethod": "paypal",
        "paymentStatus": "VERIFIED",
        "amount": 20,
        "user": "",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: I am using Mongoose 5.0.17 and my DB is hosted in Azure Cosmos DB.

Comment: I don't see any data relevant to the question here. Since this question makes no sense without relevant data I'm nominating for close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using older version of aggregation... There is new syntax for using aggregate pipeline as an array of objects.

```
exports.getDhashboard = function (req, res) {
  Registration.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: "$challenge.name",
        totalAmount: { $sum: "$amount" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
  ], function (err, registrations) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(registrations);
  });
};
```

You can see the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#) for more

Comment: Whilst it is actually "preferred" to use a wrapping array `[]` and a requirement of "some" API implementations, this is not actually true of mongoose for a [**single** pipeline stage](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L3011). So the change here actually does not do anything different. The loud error when you don't wrap with more than one stage is there for the specific reason of disallowing anything invalid.

Comment: @NeilLunn But we cannot use above syntax for mongoose version 5.x... It always throws error `Error: Aggregate has empty pipeline` and empty result... It works with mongodb but not with mongoose